# How to modify resourse in BaseAdapter?

Tags: java, android, adapter

I have customer Adapter:

```
public class AdapterListGroups extends BaseAdapter {

  private List<ItemMusicGroup> listItemsMusicGroup;
  private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
  final private String division = " ";

  public AdapterListGroups(Context context, List<ItemMusicGroup> listItemsMusicGroup) { 
      this.listItemsMusicGroup = listItemsMusicGroup;
      this.layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  } 

  @Override
  public int getCount() { 
      return this.listItemsMusicGroup.size();
  } 

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) { 
      return this.listItemsMusicGroup.get(position);
  } 

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) { 
      return position;
  } 

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
      View view = convertView;
      if ( view == null ) { 
          view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
      } 
      setContentItem(view, position);
      return view;
  } 

  private void setContentItem(View view, int position)
  { 
      ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_imageView_icon);
      imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.asses);

      ItemMusicGroup currentItemMusicGroup = getItemMusicGroup(position);

      TextView nameGroup = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_textView_nameGroup);
      nameGroup.setText(currentItemMusicGroup.getName());

      if ( currentItemMusicGroup.getCountAlbum() != null ) { 
          TextView countAlbum = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_textView_countAlbum);
          countAlbum.setText(currentItemMusicGroup.getCountAlbum() + this.division + R.string.list_item_textView_countSing);
      } 


  } 

  public ItemMusicGroup getItemMusicGroup(int position) { 
      return (ItemMusicGroup) getItem(position);
  } 
}
```

This row:

```
countAlbum.setText(currentItemMusicGroup.getCountAlbum() + this.division + R.string.list_item_textView_countSing);
```

I want to customize text of countAlbum TextView using my own text + string's const  (function getString(id) doesn't work)  in this class.

Here I get my own text + int(idResourse).

How can I make it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use **getResources().getString(R.string.example)**

Try:

```
countAlbum.setText(currentItemMusicGroup.getCountAlbum() + this.division + countAlbum.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.list_item_textView_countSing));
```